# Exposed filters - block?

Tags: 6, views

Is it possible to create a block that allows users to sort the nodes in a view? I've only been able to achieve this in a page using the menu in page settings but so far haven't had any luck with blocks. The thing is I need the block to appear on most of the site's pages. Any ideas...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is set up the exposed filters and then click Exposed form in block in the Basic Settings. This will then give you a block to use.

Answer (score 2):

There is hidden trick although "Exposed filters will not appear on block displays unless 'Use Ajax' is set to TRUE"

As of this issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/690748